# Ayuda con los patrones de diseño (Factory Method)

Tags: java, android, patrones-de-diseño

Estoy realizando una pequeña aplicación en android, en donde tengo que aplicar el patrón *Factory*, la implementación del patrón ya la he realizado y funciona, pero tengo una duda: Cuando se crea una clase concreta por medio de la fabrica, ¿Es posible acceder a un método concreto de esa clase?.

Como ejemplo de codigo, [en esta pagina](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) se explica como hacerlo pero, por ejemplo, si en la clase concreta `Square` hubiera un método adicional por ejemplo `numeroLados()`. ¿Se puede acceder cuando intente crearlo desde el main?. Algo asi como:

```
  ShapeFactory shapeFact = new ShapeFactory();
  Shape square = shapeFact.getShape("square");
  square.draw();
```

¿Cómo le hago para acceder al método `numeroLados()`?

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para acceder a un método que está en una clase más específica, puedes aplicar un [molde de tipo explícito](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-conversion-java-examples/) a esta clase.

Un molde de tipo se puede aplicar sobre un objeto para cualquiera de las clases que están en su línea de herencia, es decir, si tienes la jerarquía:

```
 Object (en java todo hereda de object)
 |-> Graphic
     |-> Shape
     |   |-> Square
     |   |-> Circle
     |-> Picture
         |-> Bitmap
```

Sobre una instancia de `Square` puedes aplicar moldes a los tipos `Shape`, `Graphic` y `Object`, y puedes referenciarlos con variables de esos tipos. Es importante recordar que una instancia no cambia de tipo por la variable que lo referencia, es de un tipo (clase) particular que se define al momento de su creación.

En otras palabras, ya que tu sabes que una instancia específica es un `Square`, podrías:

- Aplicar un molde de tipo *al vuelo* solo para llamar el método:

  ```
    ShapeFactory shapeFact = new ShapeFactory();
    Shape square = shapeFact.getShape("square");
    square.draw();
    ((Square) square).numeroLados();
  ```
- Declarar la variable como tipo `Square` y aplicar el molde de tipo desde que el objeto sale de la fábrica:

  ```
    ShapeFactory shapeFact = new ShapeFactory();
    Square square = (Square)shapeFact.getShape("square");
    square.draw();
    square.numeroLados();
  ```

Finalmente, si aplicas un molde de tipo incorrecto, vas a obtener una exepción, por ejemplo:

```
ShapeFactory shapeFact = new ShapeFactory();
Square square = (Square)shapeFact.getShape("circle");
```

Va a lanzar un error al momento de aplicar el molde de tipo a la instancia salida de la fábrica.